# Running a Dos Command from PHP

Tags: php, cygwin, dos

I am trying to use a command from PHP to print a file using cygwyn. Below is my code. I am able to use this from command line however, when I run this from the PHP, it does not work.

```
exec ('\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c "/scripts/print.sh"');
```

What may be wrong here?

**More Information:**

Script print.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

/usr/bin/lpr -d TSP143LAN /spool/order1.txt
```

where TSP143LAN is my printer.

Also I tried using directly exec command.

```
exec ('c:\cygwin\bin\lpr.exe -d TSP143LAN c:\cygwyn\spool\order1.txt', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

The output I see is

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Comment: Try giving it an output variable (second argument), for debugging. Also, check if PHP is running the command from the same folder. For example, ask it to just do `dir` and you should know where it is.

Comment: Any error message ? Did you try something simpler `exec("dir");` ?

Comment: I did. I can see the value from exec("dir"). I also tried    exec ('c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe', $output); var_dump($output); and I am seeing array (size=0)
  empty

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the full path to cygwin, ie:

```
shell_exec('C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c "/scripts/print.sh"');
```

EDIT:

Check this user's comment linked below in the php manual

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#85930

Comment: I just found a useful comment from someone in a similar situation, has a good list of things to check.